# How to query whereIn inside json column in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, json, laravel, postgresql

I have been working with a laravel 5.3 version and in a table i have a json column where i have saved average rating of a category table.
so, A product category table has a column "detail" as a json data type which saves avgRating.
I want to run a query inside that json column. And i want to filter that category with a average rating. So, from the frontend side rating comes in a parameter with a comma seperated so that category can be filtered with multiple ratings.

```
$productCategory = ProductCategory::query();
$ratings = explode(',',$params['ratings']);
$productCategory = $productCategory->whereIn('detail->avgRating',$ratings)->get();
```

I want to achieve something like this.
I am using Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there was too much uncertainty at the time when the question was asked. Once the asker separated the problems and figured out that the raw query of

```
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM product_categories where detail->>'avgRating' in ('2.0','4.0')"));
```

works in Postgres, the asker from that point onwards had a much easier time figuring out the actual solution in the `where` clause. I presuppose that it was

```
detail->>avgRating
```

instead of

```
detail->avgRating
```

but from the comment section that was not yet confirmed. But the moral of the story is that whenever one has an eloquent problem that might be related to the RDBMS, then it makes a lot of sense to first sort out the raw query and then, having solid knowledge about what should be generated, at that point one can switch to the Eloquent code and apply the solution there.

Comment: Also, do not forget to quote like this detail->>'avgRating' other wise it will consider avgRating as separate column and throws error like undefined column

Answer (score 1):

You should use `whereJsonContains`  or `whereRaw`:

```
$productCategory->whereJsonContains('detail->>avgRating',$ratings)->get();
```

OR

```
$productCategory->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(detail->>avgRating, ?)', $ratings)->get();
```

Comment: laravel 5.3 doesn't support "whereJsonContains" . and another query doesn't work. It says undefined column avgRating